# Sqlite what's the right way to make a table holding data for several tables?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I need a table `Attachments` that stores data for a number of other tables such as `Notes` and `Projects` (+many more) with the following properties:

- any other table can have many attachments
- I frequently need to find all attachments for specific entries of another table (by their primary key in that table)

I've seen in other answers to similar questions that it's best to create the attachments table and then tables like `NotesAttachments`, `ProjectsAttachments`, etc. with the Attachment, Notes and Projects IDs as foreign keys. But that looks like complex overengineering to me.

What about directly storing the table Name itself as TEXT column in `Attachments` and use that name to look for the attachments of one table whenever I need them? So basically the plan is to query for (TableName, ForeignID) to obtain all attachments with integer id `ForeignID` in table `TableName`.

Is that problematic, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attachments table now has a primary key consisting of two columns; this implies that all lookups search those two columns, and that you need a two-column index for these searches to be efficient.
But multi-column keys are a common feature in SQL databases, and are perfectly fine.

You might optimize the `TableName` column to store a short value, such as a single character, or a number. But the difference is probably not noticeable unless you have a really large amount of data.

(If you could ensure that the Notes/Projects/etc. use primary keys that are unique over all these tables, then you might be able to avoid storing the table name.)